# One site and several domains. How setup redirect?

Tags: php

I've got site on `.org` domain. Now, I'm moving it to `.com`. 
For exmaple, I've got product page, that user saved in browser `test.org/item.php?id=944`  And after user return to that page, I want to move him to the `test.com/item.php?id=944`
Should I save old site structure with redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) file to do a 301 redirect(moved permanently status code):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)test.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```